# Very simple - Histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am struggling to understand how I can get the following data into a histogram:

```
NSP <- c(1380, 6003, 1827, 661, 331, 156, 97, 73, 58) 
hist(NSP)
```

Each number should represent one bar in the exactly same order. I tried to use ggplot but failed to get the frequencies on the Y axis.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use `ggplot2`, then you likely want `geom_col`. Note that you will need to specify x-positions for the bars. Here, I am just specifying them as `1:length(NSP)` using `seq_along`:

```
ggplot(
  mapping = aes(y = NSP
                , x = seq_along(NSP))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_along(NSP))
```

[image]

If you have other labels for the breaks, you can specify them, e.g.:

```
ggplot(
  mapping = aes(y = NSP
                , x = seq_along(NSP))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_along(NSP)
                     , labels = LETTERS[seq_along(NSP)])
```

[image]

Note, however, that `ggplot` generally works much more smoothly when your data are in a data.frame. This may be a more flexible approach for you, and allow more succinct naming of the column locations (e.g., if they are not evenly spaced, you could have one column for the actual location, and one column for the label).

```
NSP_df <- data.frame(Location = LETTERS[seq_along(NSP)]
                     , Count = NSP)

ggplot(
  NSP_df
  , aes(y = Count
        , x = Location)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this and let you know if it works out!

Comment: But how do I describe the A, B, C, D and give them names? Do you happen to know that, too? Many thanks!

Comment: The exact same way I added the letters. Just replace `LETTERS[seq_along(NSP)]` with whatever labels you want to use.

Comment: Dear Mark, one last question, how can I name the axses a? I only know: xlab="NSP position - intervals",
                     ylab="Number of transactions",
                     main="NSP Distribution of Publicly Disclosed Transactions"

Comment: As lables, I wanted to use the following code:  ggplot(
  mapping = aes(y = NSP_Histo
                , x = seq_along(NSP_Histo))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_along(NSP_Histo)
                     , labels = "<0.5", "0.5-1.0", "1.0-1.5","1.5-2.0", "2.0-2.5", "2.5-3.0", "3.0-3.5", "3.5-4.0", ">4.0") - But this seems not to work

Comment: Axis labels can be added with `xlab()` and `ylab()`. The main title can be added with `ggtitle`. What do you mean by "not to work"? I do notice that you are missing a `c()` around your labels -- right now only "<0.5" is passed to `labels = `. The rest are being passed in as unnamed arguments to the `scale` function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is `barplot(NSP)`?

[image: R plot output]